# how can i change the anchor and dock style of a dynamicaly added control in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am  generating label (lblTest) dynamicaly . I need to get the center allignment of lblTest when it is maximized. I am using following c# code to adjust anchor style and dock property

```
lblTest.Anchor=AnchorStyle.None; 
lblTest.Dock=DockStyle.None;
```

but it wont work properly.
I need to change the label positon properly when the form is maximized or minimized.

Comment: What do you mean by maximised: Docked to full? If you want to set alignment to centre, it is pointless if you have autosiize on the label, so you'll have to set that too.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. The code you've written *does* work properly. It's not clear what you mean by "center alignment" and "change the label position properly".

Answer (score 1):

They are attached properties, so you will need to set them using the static methods from the defining class. Something like:

DockPanel.SetAnchor(lblTest, AnchorStyle.None);